# Storing given percentage of shape contour coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, detectron

I am building a project on Detectron2 with some mushrooms as a topic. The prediction works OK-well and I'm now trying to generate COCO-like annotations of the images with the predicted region (all XY coordinates of the region). For this, I need to do two things:

- Retrieve the XY coordinates of the predicted shape/region and "downscale it" to only save the main edges (in order to avoid saving too many data points)
- Plot the "saved" points back onto the main image for the user to judge if enough points are being saved

Unfortunately i'm failing at both. On the first point, I (think) that I have the same as a binary numpy object, but i'm surprised by its size AND i don't manage to transform it into sets of XY coordinates

On the second point, I am getting an error that I can't figure out how to debug:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/patches/__init__.py in cv2_imshow(a)
     20       image.
     21   """
---> 22   a = a.clip(0, 255).astype('uint8')
     23   # cv2 stores colors as BGR; convert to RGB
     24   if a.ndim == 3:

AttributeError: 'cv2.UMat' object has no attribute 'clip'
```

The portion of the code i'm using is here:

```py
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import ColorMode

## Predicts some random image
dataset_dicts = get_all_mushroom_dicts(mushroom_categories, "mushroom_dataset_small/val")
d = random.sample(dataset_dicts, 1)  
im = cv2.imread(d["file_name"])
mushroom_outputs = mushroom_predictor(im)
v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1],
               metadata=mushroom_metadata, 
               scale=0.8, 
               instance_mode=ColorMode.IMAGE_BW   # remove the colors of unsegmented pixels
)

instances = mushroom_outputs["instances"].to("cpu")
mush_out = v.draw_instance_predictions(instances)
image = mush_out.get_image()[:, :, ::-1]

masks = np.asarray(instances.pred_masks)
print ("NP array shape", masks.shape)
print("Image array shape", image.shape)

print("Type before", type(image))
cv2_imshow(image) ## works fine

## ?? How to get the coordinates of the boundaries? And then take only some of them

## ??

## Assuming that (128, 128) is one of these coordinates for now
image2 = cv2.circle(image, (128, 128), 10, (255, 0, 0), 20)
print("Type after", type(image2))
cv2_imshow(image2) ## crashes
```

FYI I have also tried to find and draw the contour but this doesn't seem to work (see my post here https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/1702#event-3501434732 ).

Do you have any clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution that works but part of it is not elegant:

Retrieve the XY coordinates:

```
masks = np.asarray(instances.pred_masks)
cnt, heirarchy = cv2.findContours(masks[0].astype("uint8"), cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
border = cnt[0]
gap = 20 # take only every 20 point
for i in list(range(border.shape[0]))[0::gap]:
  y = int(border[i][0][1]*0.8)
  x = int(border[i][0][0]*0.8)
  print("New XY coordinates", (x,y))
```

Draw on the picture:

```
image_old = mush_out.get_image()[:, :, ::-1]
cv2.imwrite("img.png", image_old)
image = cv2.imread("img.png",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) # Still no clue why this is needed but doesnt work if you dont save and re-read...
radius = 3
color = (255, 0, 0)
cv2.circle(image, (x, y), radius, color, -1) # my previous code was wrong; cv2.circle returns void and edits directly the image 
cv2_imshow(image)
```